# JQuery UI Datepicker currently displayed months

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

Im using datepicker in div with this configuration"

> ```
> $("#homeDatepicker").datepicker({
>     numberOfMonths: 3,
>     dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
>     firstDay: '1'
>     ...
> });
> ```

how do i know which monts are currently displayed in div (user can navigate to display next and previous one).

i want to load some external data using ajax depending on this data.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in this link http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#multiple-calendars
The current month based on today's date and followed by next two months are displayed.

Comment: you are right. but
im displaying calendar in div
you have next and prev buttons. i want to know which monts are currently presented to user. i dont care selected day.

Comment: If i understood you correctly, once the datepicker shows up you need to find out the months that are available. You can try this.    currDate = $('#homeDatepicker').datepicker( "getDate" );                 currDate.getMonth(); which prints out 0 which is january. Since you are displaying numberOfMonths which is three you can figure out the next two months are 1 and 2 which is february and march.

Comment: If the user changes selects middle month are the third month then the addition wont work. As long is it is done onshow of datepicker the above code works. thanks